# PhoneGap - Splash screen issue with Cordova in ios 7

Tags: iphone, cordova, ios7, splash-screen

Currently I am working on Phonegap app and i have one issue with Splash screen. When the app launch the splash screen jump horizantally.

You help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your splash image size?

Comment: First check your splash screen size  or replace splash screen with ur old iphone project , u will get the solution where u have issue .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think it's a  splash screen size issue ,so Please update the splash screen size with .

`IPHONE SPLASH

```
Default.png - 320 x 480

Default@2x.png - 640 x 960 

Default-568h@2x.png - 640 x 1096


IPAD SPLASH
```

iPadImage-Appname-Portrait.png * 768w x 1004h

iPadImage-Appname-Portrait@2x.png * 1536w x 2008h

`iPadImage-Appname-Landscape.png ** 1024w x 748h

`iPadImage-Appname-Landscape@2x.png ** 2048w x 1496h

Comment: Also Please check it from which folder iphone splash screen will take and make sure u have not 2 copies of same splash screen .check in www -> resource folder and application resource folder .

Comment: We have also phonegap developer chat you can join it.http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11300/phonegap-framework